# Correct order of surahs in prayers

Tags: quran, salat

**Question 1**: Is it OK to recite the 4 Qul ([109](https://quran.com/109), [112](https://quran.com/112), [113](https://quran.com/113), and [114](https://quran.com/114)) in 4 rak'ahs of any nafl prayer in the order below:

1. [Surat Al-Kafirun](https://quran.com/109)
2. [Surat Al-Ikhlas](https://quran.com/112)
3. [Surat Al-Falaq](https://quran.com/113)
4. [Surat An-Nas](https://quran.com/114)

Is this order acceptable, especially since Surat Al-Ikhlas is the shortest among these four surahs?

---

**Question 2:** Is it allowed to recite a small surah (like [Surat Al-Kawthar 108](https://quran.com/108)) in the first rak'ah followed by any other surah (like [Surat Quraysh 106](https://quran.com/106)) with Surah 108 being shorter in length and having fewer ayahs?

Comment: Your question does not make sense and should be better formatted!

Answer (score 1):

Except for the maliki school of fiqh all sunni schools wouldn't complain no matter what order you chose. The maliki's would rather -prefer to- stick on the order of the quran (not the length of a sura which is basically irrelevant). Also read: [What does reading surahs during salah in a reverse way mean?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/what-does-reading-surahs-during-salah-in-a-reverse-way-mean) (where you may find evidences for my claims).

I just wonder in what sunna (nafl) prayers you may recite in four raka', al-Fatiha + sura (except for the night prayers). Note that you even could recite randomly two or three etc. of them in one single raka'a or even repeat the same.

These might also be relevant:
[Can we recite two or more surahs in one rakat when praying?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30669/can-we-recite-two-or-more-surahs-in-one-rakat-when-praying)
[Surah recitation during salah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44154/surah-recitation-during-salah)

Answer (score 0):

As your first answer.
That is right order of 4Qul. We can also get that from Quran. 
But this pattern is only for sunnah-gair mokedah (in Asar, Isha). 
May Allah forgive us.

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer]. Please add your evidence that this order is acceptable, and is only for _sunnah ghair  mu'akkadah_.